# Simple if in batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

For some reason my batch script always closes when the following if is executed

```
IF %LAST_TS_ERROR%=="-1"(
 cd %mypath%plugins\"
 ren TeaConnect_win64.dll TeaConnect_win64.dll.OFF
)
```

In case you need to know: last_ts_error is

```
SET LAST_TS_ERROR=%ErrorLevel%
```

Comment: What happens if you just use `Echo %ERRORLEVEL%`, because if you were to do that, you'd note that it most certainly isn't surrounded by doublequotes. So change it to `IF "%LAST_TS_ERROR%"=="-1" (` instead.

Comment: I enclosed it in quotes like you said but it still crashes, now also after executing the code directly from the console i see: "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and run the batch file by typing its path/name rather than double-clicking it, so you'll see any error messages. You have unbalanced quotes and a missing space in front of `(`, and depending on the content of `%LAST_TS_ERROR%`, I guess you are trying to compare `-1` with `"-1"`...

Comment: You're my hero. The missing space was the culprit °!°

Answer (score 0):

as @aschipfl mentioned, it seems you are expecting an error level of `-1` and you are then atempting to match `-1` with `"-1"` which will never be true, also you have a missing space before the `(`, so simply do  (your current code version):

```
IF "%LAST_TS_ERROR%"=="-1" (
 pushd "%mypath%\plugins\"
 ren TeaConnect_win64.dll TeaConnect_win64.dll.OFF
 popd
)
```

or perhaps a shorter version?:

```
if "%errorlevel%"=="-1" ren "%mypath%\TeaConnect_win64.dll" "%mypath%\TeaConnect_win64.dll.OFF"
```